# Is Fingerprint authentication is as good as modifying Shared Preferences?

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-sharedpreferences, android-security, android-fingerprint-api

I am adding fingerprint authentication in my app at launch I read a boolean variable from preferences to decide if fingerprint authentication is enabled or not. I am wondering how easy it is to modify shared preferences of another app. Seems like its really easy thing to do [Android: Modify SharedPreferences of another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522037/android-modify-sharedpreferences-of-another-app).

Does this mean that fingerprint authentication used based on shared preference is useless?

Every sample that I found relied on such preferences. E.g. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog

Answer (score 0):

I once modified my App's Shared Preferences XML file manually without any issue, so I guess it is not safe to store that config value there.